# Updating JSON with shopify variant change

Tags: javascript, json, shopify

I am trying to add a preorder date to change dynamically when a variant is selected.
All appears to work other than the final preOrderDate[variant_id] is returning 'undefined'.

```
{% capture 'meta_data' %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {{ variant.id}}: {{ variant.metafields.custom.pre_order_due_date.value | json}} {%- comment -%} Replace it with your NAMESPACE.KEY value {%- endcomment -%}
  {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
<script>
```

metafields.custom.pre_order_due_date contains a data metafield.

meta_data returns:

44299040686393: "2023-06-23" , 44299040719161: null

```
<script>

  var metaData = { {{ meta_data }} };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var selector = document.querySelector('input[name=id]');
    if(selector) {
      selector.addEventListener('change', function() {
        let variant_id = this.value;;
          if(!variant_id) return;
          var preOrderDate = metaData[variant_id],
            meta = document.querySelector('#preOrderDateText'); // Find your class which has metafiled
          if(preOrderDate && meta) {
            meta.innerHTML = preOrderDate;
          }
      })
    }
  });

</script>
```

when implementing metaData[variant_id] returns 'undefined'

I've also tried:

metaData[44299040686393]

which also returns 'undefined'

Any help appreciated.